# Ghub lua unbind "back" to mouse button #4

Tags: lua

I'm currently trying to use Ghub's lua scripting function (on Mac) so that when I hold down mouse button 4/5, I can repeatedly scroll up/down, until mouse button 4/5 is released. The following is a code snippet of what I have

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" then
       if arg == 5 then
         repeat
            MoveMouseWheel(-60)
            Sleep(50)
            OutputLogMessage(tostring(IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)))
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)
       elseif arg == 4 then
         repeat
            MoveMouseWheel(60)
            Sleep(50)
            OutputLogMessage(tostring(IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)))
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)
      end
   end
end
```

The code indeed does what it's supposed to do, except for the fact that when I release mouse button 4/5, it also simulates the default back/forward behavior (for example, on Chrome). I originally thought my script would supersede the default behavior, but it seems that's not true.

**Question**. How would one unbind the default behavior? (And does this always happen with lua scripting?)

**Update**. I have attempted to follow @Eskri's comment and assign LShift/RShift to (physical) mouse 4/5 and use the following code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" then
       if arg == 5 then
         repeat
            MoveMouseWheel(-60)
            Sleep(50)
         until not IsModifierPressed("RShift")
       elseif arg == 4 then
         repeat
            MoveMouseWheel(60)
            Sleep(50)
         until not IsModifierPressed("LShift")
      end
   end
end
```

However, the code won't repeat itself when I'm holding down the (physical) mouse 4/5 buttons, for some reason.

Comment: In GHub there is a big picture of mouse, you should drop-down a list for button #4/5 and select `DISABLE`.  This will disable default "Back/Forward' action.  But your script will not work anymore, because `IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)` relies on this default button action.

Comment: As a workaround, you can assign `LShift/RShift` actions for physical buttons 4/5 and replace `IsMouseButtonPressed(arg)` with `IsModifierPressed("LShift/RShift")`

Comment: But wouldn't that mean if I were to press my physical LShift/RShift, I would also be scrolling?

Comment: No.  Physical LShift/RShift will only prevent scroll from stopping.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Isn't "prevent scroll from stopping" the same as just scrolling?

Comment: The scrolling STARTS with `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED` event independently of Shift key state.  The scrolling STOPS when Shift is not pressed.  So, it is impossible to start the scrolling with physical Shift.  BTW, you can use the same key (for example, RShift of LCtrl or RAlt) for both `arg==4` and `arg==5` branches of code: assign `RAlt` to both physical buttons 4/5 and use the same invocation `IsModifierPressed("RAlt")` in both `until` conditions.